# How to toggle glyphicon icon on toggle of a span in django templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a span which is inside a loop in django templates.

```
{% for book in books%}
<span class="book-list" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sheets_list{{workbook.id }}">
    {{book.name}}
    <span class="toggle_sign glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> 
    <span class="date"> Last Update Time= {{book.reg_date}}</span>
</span>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to toggle the icon up and down on expand and collapse but also make sure that it doesnot effect other span as the loop will bring multiple span for book names.

I have tried

```
$('.toggle_sign').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

But it doesnt do anything on toggle sign's class.
Any help please?

Comment: Typo : `$('.toogle_sign')` instead of `$('.toggle_sign')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this he working code here.

and you have also pass the wrong class name to event.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.parentDiv').click(function() {

      var toggle_sign = $(this).find(".toggle_sign");
      if ($(toggle_sign).hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-down")) {
        $(toggle_sign).removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
      } else {
        $(toggle_sign).addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
      }
      // or toggle event you can use.
      //$(toggle_sign).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
    });
  });
```

```css
.parentDiv {
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
  height: 50px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <span class="toggle_sign glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</div>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <span class="toggle_sign glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</div>
```

Hope so this will help you a lot

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake.I want the functionalitysuch that on click of anywhere in the span as the toggle happens,the icon should change. not only when it is clicked on the icon.

Comment: I have modify the code please have a look on it hope so this will help you a lot. This will not complete solution but a hint for you so please keep in mind.

Comment: thanx for help. but as per your exmple there will be more than one div having class "parentDiv" and on click of any one will chnage the icon on every div.and thats the issue

Comment: I provided you only hint.

Comment: But that was my question, how to achieve this when we got more than i parent div or span

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103824/discussion-between-rahul-and-amangupta).

Comment: i have added the new edited code here where i used find method to select the span please have a look on it